# fail to scan a chain of task_struct

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am trying to get a list of all PIDs in a kernel module without useful APIs for some reason.

The code is here. I tried to scan all existing task_struct objects connected with `sibling`/`children` member in `struct task_struct`.

```c
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init_task.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

#define MODNAME "list_pid"
#define MINOR_COUNT 1

static void printk_pid_children(struct task_struct *parent_ts){
    struct task_struct *fst = container_of(parent_ts->children.next, struct task_struct, sibling);
    struct task_struct *t = fst;
    if(fst != parent_ts){
        do { 
            printk("%d,", t->tgid);
            printk_pid_children(t);
            t = list_next_entry(t, sibling);
        } while(t != fst);
    }
}

static int __init list_pid_init(void){
    printk("%s\n",__func__);
    printk("%d,", init_task.pid);
    printk_pid_children(&init_task);
    printk("\n");

    return 0;
}
module_init(list_pid_init);

static void __exit list_pid_exit(void){
}
module_exit(list_pid_exit);
```

However, after `sudo insmod list_pid.ko`, the system hangs up.
What is wrong in the above code?

Thank you.

Comment: Invalid concurrent access of some sort, as you're not bothering to obey any locking protocols when accessing shared data structures.

Comment: You have `while(t != fst)` loop, but `t` is never modified in that loop. Also, when iterate over linked lists in the Linux kernel, end condition should be like `(entry != head)`, not `(entry != first_entry)` as in your code. `without useful APIs for some reason.` - I suggest you first to organize iteration **with** usefull API (like `for_each_process`). If you success with that, you may replace these API with low-level functions.